# Setting corner radius hides UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, rounded-corners

I've created this extension to quickly add rounded corners to any `UIView`:

```
extension UIView {
    func setCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        print(self.frame) //-> (359.0, 0.0, 306.0, 37.0)
        let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.frame, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: 0.0))
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = maskLayer
        print(self.frame) //-> (359.0, 0.0, 306.0, 37.0)
    }
}
```

The code I use to create the view and round its corners:

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 40))) //I reposition the view later
view.setCorners(corners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], radius: 8)
```

When commenting out the `setCorners(corners:radius:)`, the view appears, while it stays hidden otherwise.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I'm not sure what a corner radius with a height of zero is.  The corner radius should have a height and width... usually (for circular corners) it would have the same width and height.  What happens if you change your corner radius to be square?

Comment: Still disappears... Like, it doesn't even appear at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, that you need use self.bounds instead self.frame in `UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.frame, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: 0.0))`

Comment: I actually like this even better because it's shorter. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 2):

You are masking a wrong view area, try this:

```
let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height), byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: 0.0))
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks!

Comment: Or just use self.bounds instead of self.frame